# i have a problem adding fleet cart to my WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress

error
https://card.triplediamond-hf.com/

rror
Class 'PDO' not found
https://card.triplediamond-hf.com/

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:1335

```
    return static::$resolvers[$driver] ?? null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you need to install the PDO driver on your server. In ubuntu, this can be done with the following command:

```
sudo apt install pdo pdo-mysql
```

However your post is a little misleading. The subject and tags mention WordPress, but your post and code seem to indicate a Laravel project. Either way, with an error that the PDO class isn't found you'll need to get that PHP extension installed.

Here's a link to the PHP PDO documenation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php